# How to check whether two labels fall on the same page?

Tags: cross-referencing, conditionals

I'd like to have something like `5--10` in the header of an article (my document is a journal issue) if it spans the pages 5-10, and `5` (as opposed to `5--5`) if it is short and fits on one page.  I use `\label`s in some hooks when including the individual articles which insert things like `\label{\articlename:beginning}` and `\label{\articlename:ending}`.  Now the question is: how to check whether the two labels fall on the same page?  Currently, I use something like

```
\pageref{\articlename:beginning}%
\expandafter\ifx\csname r@\articlename:beginning\expandafter\endcsname
  \csname r@\articlename:ending\endcsname\else
  --\pageref{\subjobname:end}%
\fi
```

(Quite obviously, this can be simplified using `etoolbox`'s `\ifcsequal` – I'm in the process of moving to `etoolbox` and that's why I didn't use it before.)

My question is: is there a better way than using `\csname r@ something\endcsname` (or its equivalent with `etoolbox`), which seems to me a bit dirty-hackish?  Maybe there's a ready-made package for this?  (`varioref` comes to mind, which does similar things, but AFAIK it does not have any public interface like `\iflabelsonthesamepage{label1}{label2}{true}{false}`.)

Comment: I am using the [`refcount`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/refcount) package for this task.

Comment: @Malipivo: this is great!  Can you write an answer about `refcount`?

Comment: I can't do that right now, but I can do that tomorrow, well I am sure someone will be faster with answering this nice question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a solution based on `refcount` and `etoolbox`. I made a new command called `pagespan`, which prints your output wherever placed:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{refcount}

\newcommand{\pagespan}[2]{%
    \ifnumequal{\getpagerefnumber{#1}}{\getpagerefnumber{#2}}{%
        \pageref{#1}%
    }%
    {%
        \pageref{#1}--\pageref{#2}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}
\label{start}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\label{end}

Should be different (dash-dash expected): \pagespan{start}{end}

\newpage
\label{start2}
\lipsum[1]
\label{end2}

Should be the same (one number expected): \pagespan{start2}{end2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You had *several* spurious spaces in your code.